# Fading in a body gradient on document load in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm starting out coding my website, and what I *want* to happen is when the document loads, a gradient background will fade in for about 500 milliseconds. However, I cannot seem to do this no matter what I try.

Here is my code so far:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#gradient').css('display', 'none').fadeIn(500)
});
```

```css
#gradient {
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgb(0, 134, 255), rgb(0, 62, 123));
 background: radial-gradient(rgb(0, 134, 255), rgb(0, 62, 123));
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/login.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
        
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body id="gradient">
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried just about everything, but I cannot get it to fade! The gradient stays fully opaque while the opacity is being animated.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to fade the body itself but a DOM element inside it.
I created a new DIV-layer calling it `#gradient` and setting it to `display none`.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#gradient').fadeIn(500)
});
```

```css
#gradient {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgb(0, 134, 255), rgb(0, 62, 123));
    background: radial-gradient(rgb(0, 134, 255), rgb(0, 62, 123));
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/login.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
        
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gradient"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beat me to a response! This is the right way to do it. Be especially wary of making changes to the actual `body` element!

Comment: This worked! Guess I can't pass the fadeIn() function to the body. And I tried putting the gradient class on a div, but I just forgot to add the size parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.animate** as well.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#gradient').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 5000);       
});
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin    : 0;
    height    : 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#gradient {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgb(0, 134, 255), rgb(0, 62, 123));
  background: radial-gradient(rgb(0, 134, 255), rgb(0, 62, 123));  
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="gradient">

    </div>
</body>
```